# Slide-up animation of text-articles from outside the viewport. How to hide and scroll texts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

On my blog I have multiple text-articles that should be displayed by clicking the titles in a menu.

First, only the menu with an overview of all texts is visible (no scroll). When a title is clicked the corresponding text should *slide-up* from the bottom of the viewport – now the text should be scrollable. When another title is clicked the first text should *slide-down* and the next *slide-up*.

My problem is the display / visibility of the texts outside the viewport and the scrollability.

---

Texts outside the viewport should be hidden.
Text inside the viewport should be scrollable.

---

I don't know how to continue from the point you see below. Any help or tip is highly appreciated!

HTML

```
<nav class="menu">
<div class="menuautohrtexts">
    
    <div id="text1m" class="menuline">
    <a id="author1" class="menuauthors" href="#/text1">Author 1</a>
    <a id="text1" class="menutexts" href="#/text1">Text 1</a>
    </div>

    <div id="text2m" class="menuline">
    <a id="author2" class="menuauthors" href="#/text2">Author 2</a>
    <a id="text2" class="menutexts" href="#/text2">Text 2</a>
    </div>

    <div id="text3m" class="menuline">
    <a id="author3" class="menuauthors" href="#/text3">Author 3</a>
    <a id="text3" class="menutexts" href="#/text3">Text 3</a>
    </div>
    
    <div id="text4m" class="menuline">
    <a id="author4" class="menuauthors" href="#/text4">Author 4</a>
    <a id="text4" class="menutexts" href="#/text4">Text 4</a>
    </div>

</div>
</nav>

<article class="content">
<div class="text1" id="text1c">

    <div class="textinfo">
        <h2 class="textauthor">Name 1</h2>
        <h2 class="texttitle">Title 1</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="textcontent">
        <p>Text 1</p>
    </div>
        
</div>

<div class="text2" id="text2c">

    <div class="textinfo">
        <h2 class="textauthor">Name 2</h2>
        <h2 class="texttitle">Title 2</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="textcontent">
        <p>Text 2</p>
    </div>
        
</div>

<div class="text3" id="text3c">

    <div class="textinfo">
        <h2 class="textauthor">Name 3</h2>
        <h2 class="texttitle">Title 3</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="textcontent">
        <p>Text 3</p>
    </div>
        
</div>

<div class="text4" id="text4c">

    <div class="textinfo">
        <h2 class="textauthor">Name 4</h2>
        <h2 class="texttitle">Title 4</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="textcontent">
        <p>Text 4</p>
    </div>
        
</div>
</article>
```

CSS

```
.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.text1 , .text2 , .text3 , .text4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100vh;
    transition: top 500ms ease;
}

.textup1 , .textup2 , .textup3 , .textup4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0vh;
}
```

JS

```
// MENU
var text1m = document.getElementById("text1m");
var text2m = document.getElementById("text2m");
var text3m = document.getElementById("text3m");
var text4m = document.getElementById("text4m");

// CONTENT
var text1c = document.getElementById("text1c");
var text2c = document.getElementById("text2c");
var text3c = document.getElementById("text3c");
var text4c = document.getElementById("text4c");

text1m.addEventListener("click", function () {
    text1c.classList.add("textup1");
    text2c.classList.remove("textup2");
    text3c.classList.remove("textup3");
    text4c.classList.remove("textup4");
});

text2m.addEventListener("click", function () {
    text2c.classList.add("textup2");
    text1c.classList.remove("textup1");
    text3c.classList.remove("textup3");
    text4c.classList.remove("textup4");
});

text3m.addEventListener("click", function () {
    text3c.classList.add("textup3");
    text1c.classList.remove("textup1");
    text2c.classList.remove("textup2");
    text4c.classList.remove("textup4");
});

text4m.addEventListener("click", function () {
    text4c.classList.add("textup4");
    text1c.classList.remove("textup1");
    text2c.classList.remove("textup2");
    text3c.classList.remove("textup3");
});
```

```js
// MENU
var text1m = document.getElementById("text1m");
var text2m = document.getElementById("text2m");
var text3m = document.getElementById("text3m");
var text4m = document.getElementById("text4m");

// CONTENT
var text1c = document.getElementById("text1c");
var text2c = document.getElementById("text2c");
var text3c = document.getElementById("text3c");
var text4c = document.getElementById("text4c");

text1m.addEventListener("click", function () {
    text1c.classList.add("textup1");
    text2c.classList.remove("textup2");
    text3c.classList.remove("textup3");
    text4c.classList.remove("textup4");
});

text2m.addEventListener("click", function () {
    text2c.classList.add("textup2");
    text1c.classList.remove("textup1");
    text3c.classList.remove("textup3");
    text4c.classList.remove("textup4");
});

text3m.addEventListener("click", function () {
    text3c.classList.add("textup3");
    text1c.classList.remove("textup1");
    text2c.classList.remove("textup2");
    text4c.classList.remove("textup4");
});

text4m.addEventListener("click", function () {
    text4c.classList.add("textup4");
    text1c.classList.remove("textup1");
    text2c.classList.remove("textup2");
    text3c.classList.remove("textup3");
});
```

```css
.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.text1 , .text2 , .text3 , .text4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100vh;
    transition: top 500ms ease;
}

.textup1 , .textup2 , .textup3 , .textup4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0vh;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
<div class="menuautohrtexts">
    
    <div id="text1m" class="menuline">
    <a id="author1" class="menuauthors" href="#/text1">Author 1</a>
    <a id="text1" class="menutexts" href="#/text1">Text 1</a>
    </div>

    <div id="text2m" class="menuline">
    <a id="author2" class="menuauthors" href="#/text2">Author 2</a>
    <a id="text2" class="menutexts" href="#/text2">Text 2</a>
    </div>

    <div id="text3m" class="menuline">
    <a id="author3" class="menuauthors" href="#/text3">Author 3</a>
    <a id="text3" class="menutexts" href="#/text3">Text 3</a>
    </div>
    
    <div id="text4m" class="menuline">
    <a id="author4" class="menuauthors" href="#/text4">Author 4</a>
    <a id="text4" class="menutexts" href="#/text4">Text 4</a>
    </div>

</div>
</nav>

<article class="content">
<div class="text1" id="text1c">

    <div class="textinfo">
        <h2 class="textauthor">Name 1</h2>
        <h2 class="texttitle">Title 1</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="textcontent">
        <p>Text 1</p>
    </div>
        
</div>

<div class="text2" id="text2c">

    <div class="textinfo">
        <h2 class="textauthor">Name 2</h2>
        <h2 class="texttitle">Title 2</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="textcontent">
        <p>Text 2</p>
    </div>
        
</div>

<div class="text3" id="text3c">

    <div class="textinfo">
        <h2 class="textauthor">Name 3</h2>
        <h2 class="texttitle">Title 3</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="textcontent">
        <p>Text 3</p>
    </div>
        
</div>

<div class="text4" id="text4c">

    <div class="textinfo">
        <h2 class="textauthor">Name 4</h2>
        <h2 class="texttitle">Title 4</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="textcontent">
        <p>Text 4</p>
    </div>
        
</div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolute positioning breaks elements from the flow. That results in that the container doesn't know how large it should be to fit the children. But I understand that you need to overlap the elements in order to animate them in the right position, but you can use CSS Grid for that. That will give you power to overlap, without breaking the flow.

Make the `.content` element a grid container with a single row and single column. Place the your text elements inside the container and place each item in the single grid. Also make sure that `overflow: hidden` is added to hide anything out of the element's view.

Now use [CSS Transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transforms/Using_CSS_transforms) to move your elements out of the view of the parent container. Transforms allow elements to move without distorting the flow of elements. This means that your `.content` container has the size of it's children, while the children have moved out of view.

```js
const texts = document.querySelectorAll('.text');

const menuTexts = document.querySelectorAll('.menuauthors, .menutexts');
for (const menuText of menuTexts) {
  menuText.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const url = new URL(event.target.href);
    const id = url.hash.substring(2);

    for (const text of texts) {
      text.classList.toggle('textup', text.id === id);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.content {
  display: grid;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text {
  grid-area: 1 / 1;
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  transition: transform 500ms ease;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.text.textup {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <div class="menuautohrtexts">
    <div id="text1m" class="menuline">
      <a id="author1" class="menuauthors" href="#/text1c">Author 1</a>
      <a id="text1" class="menutexts" href="#/text1c">Text 1</a>
    </div>

    <div id="text2m" class="menuline">
      <a id="author2" class="menuauthors" href="#/text2c">Author 2</a>
      <a id="text2" class="menutexts" href="#/text2c">Text 2</a>
    </div>

    <div id="text3m" class="menuline">
      <a id="author3" class="menuauthors" href="#/text3c">Author 3</a>
      <a id="text3" class="menutexts" href="#/text3c">Text 3</a>
    </div>

    <div id="text4m" class="menuline">
      <a id="author4" class="menuauthors" href="#/text4c">Author 4</a>
      <a id="text4" class="menutexts" href="#/text4c">Text 4</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>

<article class="content">
  <div class="text" id="text1c">

    <div class="textinfo">
      <h2 class="textauthor">Name 1</h2>
      <h2 class="texttitle">Title 1</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="textcontent">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet id hac labore tristique fusce pharetra consectetur libero dui. Purus curabitur facilisi auctor euismod ac leo magna. Vestibulum elit sodales nisi purus odio consequat scelerisque dapibus gravida sed lobortis. Labore euismod urna hendrerit tortor duis platea elit urna luctus enim iaculis nisl vitae. Laoreet nisl sollicitudin lectus aliquam sodales purus incididunt pretium maecenas incididunt.</p>

<p>Vitae aliquet convallis lacus fames fringilla auctor aliqua sed curabitur auctor. Aliqua tincidunt arcu laoreet hac elementum mattis orci in vivamus libero quis iaculis massa. Eu molestie nullam fermentum elementum ac volutpat urna sagittis habitasse. Augue praesent mattis iaculis congue facilisi nullam praesent turpis. Faucibus dapibus ut leo pulvinar fames scelerisque labore donec.</p>

<p>Orci quisque vulputate etiam tempus magna pretium vestibulum lacinia ultricies libero blandit praesent volutpat elementum. Malesuada pretium bibendum sed semper tristique platea id consectetur quam. Mollis fusce mollis pulvinar arcu velit fermentum elit ut morbi sodales enim neque. Egestas suspendisse bibendum tortor do vivamus curabitur eros lobortis blandit egestas dictum lobortis et turpis. A convallis massa sed curabitur tempus suspendisse lectus euismod.</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="text" id="text2c">

    <div class="textinfo">
      <h2 class="textauthor">Name 2</h2>
      <h2 class="texttitle">Title 2</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="textcontent">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet labore magna pretium. Fames rhoncus arcu pulvinar facilisis integer aliqua nulla dui. Neque scelerisque arcu porta velit fermentum blandit quisque arcu nunc odio. Netus cursus nisi duis vivamus ultricies vulputate enim a eu dolore etiam vestibulum. Magna pharetra integer facilisi eleifend erat at quisque nibh.</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="text" id="text3c">
    <div class="textinfo">
      <h2 class="textauthor">Name 3</h2>
      <h2 class="texttitle">Title 3</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="textcontent">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet id hac labore tristique fusce pharetra consectetur libero dui. Purus curabitur facilisi auctor euismod ac leo magna. Vestibulum elit sodales nisi purus odio consequat scelerisque dapibus gravida sed lobortis. Labore euismod urna hendrerit tortor duis platea elit urna luctus enim iaculis nisl vitae. Laoreet nisl sollicitudin lectus aliquam sodales purus incididunt pretium maecenas incididunt.</p>

<p>Vitae aliquet convallis lacus fames fringilla auctor aliqua sed curabitur auctor. Aliqua tincidunt arcu laoreet hac elementum mattis orci in vivamus libero quis iaculis massa. Eu molestie nullam fermentum elementum ac volutpat urna sagittis habitasse. Augue praesent mattis iaculis congue facilisi nullam praesent turpis. Faucibus dapibus ut leo pulvinar fames scelerisque labore donec.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="text" id="text4c">

    <div class="textinfo">
      <h2 class="textauthor">Name 4</h2>
      <h2 class="texttitle">Title 4</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="textcontent">
      <p>Text 4</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</article>
```

Sidenote: be sure that your `href` values match `id` attributes of any elements on the page, otherwise they'll be useless. Consider using `<button>` elements when you require interaction without navigation.

Comment: Placing all items in the same grid cell makes the `grid-template-*` declarations redundant. Further, the third and fourth value of `grid-area` can be omitted (for the default value `span 1`): The first two values then effectively indicate the grid cell in which to place the item.

Comment: Note that you can also use `translateY()` instead of `translate3d()`.

Comment: Dear Emiel, thanks a lot for your answer and stripping down my code! It seems to be a good way, but I still have some issues: My texts have different length. With this solution the scroll-bar always shows the length of the longest text. Even if no text is displayed the empty grid can be scrolled. Is there a way to change this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @OskarGrosser good call on keeping the code lean. Sometimes I do like it when code is verbose and explicit, like with CSS Grid, however your suggestion is a good one to follow if you're writing CSS in an effecient manner. I always tend to use `translate3d` with animations/transitions because it uses hardware acceleration. I believe `translateY` does not, since it's in a 2d plane. Correct my if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Felix You could give the `.content` div a fixed height so that you control the minimal height of every child, and add `overflow: scroll` to the children. I've modified the example. What should it look like in your opinion?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Several articles agree that `translate3d()` (usually) forces hardware-acceleration where the other translate functions may not. But I do agree with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28148344/13561410): We should assume (especially with declarative languages like CSS) that browsers are better at knowing when and what to optimize.

Comment: @OskarGrosser I like your thoughts and apploud taking the time to research the topic. I've been using it like this since first reading about it, which is a couple of years back by now. Time to shake things up.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier The steps I want to achieve: 1. Only menu visible, no text no scrollbar. 2. On click text A slides up from bottom of the browser window. Scrollbar shows the correct length for text A. No empty space underneath (shorter) text! 3. On click text A slides down, along with the scrollbar. Text B slides up, scrollbar shows the length of text B. etc. Instead of having a grid with fixed height, is it possible to use the remaining height of browser window (minus menu) for text and scrollbar? With the grid solution I don’t get variable heights for different text lengths and browser sizes.

Answer (score 0):

i have made some changes like wrapping all html with a class name container and changing css avoid using position absolute during animation use transform or use overflow hiddden to avoid scroll bar

```css
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      text-decoration: none;
      list-style: none;
    }

    .container {
      height: 100vh;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .text1,
    .text2,
    .text3,
    .text4 {
      position: absolute;
      transform: translateY(100vh);
      transition: transform 500ms ease;
    }

    .textup1,
    .textup2,
    .textup3,
    .textup4 {
      transform: translateY(0vh);
    }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="menu">
      <div class="menuautohrtexts">
        <div id="text1m" class="menuline">
          <a id="author1" class="menuauthors" href="#/text1">Author 1</a>
          <a id="text1" class="menutexts" href="#/text1">Text 1</a>
        </div>

        <div id="text2m" class="menuline">
          <a id="author2" class="menuauthors" href="#/text2">Author 2</a>
          <a id="text2" class="menutexts" href="#/text2">Text 2</a>
        </div>

        <div id="text3m" class="menuline">
          <a id="author3" class="menuauthors" href="#/text3">Author 3</a>
          <a id="text3" class="menutexts" href="#/text3">Text 3</a>
        </div>

        <div id="text4m" class="menuline">
          <a id="author4" class="menuauthors" href="#/text4">Author 4</a>
          <a id="text4" class="menutexts" href="#/text4">Text 4</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <article class="content">
      <div class="text1" id="text1c">
        <div class="textinfo">
          <h2 class="textauthor">Name 1</h2>
          <h2 class="texttitle">Title 1</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="textcontent">
          <p>Text 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="text2" id="text2c">
        <div class="textinfo">
          <h2 class="textauthor">Name 2</h2>
          <h2 class="texttitle">Title 2</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="textcontent">
          <p>Text 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="text3" id="text3c">
        <div class="textinfo">
          <h2 class="textauthor">Name 3</h2>
          <h2 class="texttitle">Title 3</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="textcontent">
          <p>Text 3</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="text4" id="text4c">
        <div class="textinfo">
          <h2 class="textauthor">Name 4</h2>
          <h2 class="texttitle">Title 4</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="textcontent">
          <p>Text 4</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
```